# Ctrl Alt Function terminal doesn't work in Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, terminal, debian

I have installed Debian Wheezy a few days after it was released. I cannot use Ctrl + Alt + Function terminal because when I try to switch to one of them I get a view of starting screen. I mean screen with starting messages:

```
Loading, please wait...
INIT: version 2.88 booting
[info] Using makefile-style concurent boot in runlevel S.
[ ok ] Starting the hotplug events dispatcher: udevd.
[ ok ] Synthesizing the initial hotplug events...done.
[....] Waiting for /dev to be fully populated[   7.287563] [drm:pch_irq_handler] *ERROR* pch poison interrupt
```

I don't know what should I do. I think it can be caused by the problem with /dev (terminals are /dev/tty*).

Here is my **dmesg** log: http://pastebin.com/WgRPDAcQ. Error is in line no.784.

Comment: When you say "Ctrl+Alt+Function", do you mean "Ctrl+Alt+F1" ? If so, try F2 instead of F1, or F3. You should get different virtual terminals. If that doesn't work, try pressing the return key on the terminal with the kernel messages.

Comment: I've tried it many times, believe me. None of F1-F6 terminals work. Enter button also does not help.